# Build node.js addon without node-waf

Tags: node.js, g++, eclipse-cdt

I'm writing a simple node.js addon in C++ using Eclipse CDT. The project has many files and I'd like to use the Eclipse's managed build system.

I can compile a simple addon example with `node-waf`, but I can't configure my Eclipse toolchain to build a proper shared library without waf. Waf uses gcc behind the scenes, so I'm sure it's possible.

Which libs should I link to and what kind of options should I pass along to make it work?

Currently I get the following error if I try to `require` my lib:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

Required compiler flags:

```
g++ 
    -g 
    -fPIC 
    -DPIC 
    -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE 
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 
    -D_GNU_SOURCE 
    -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 
    -I/usr/local/include/node 
    addon.cc 
    -c 
    -o addon.o
```

Linker flags:

```
g++ addon.o -o addon.node -shared -L/usr/local/lib
```

**Importand note:**

The shared library *must* have the extension `.node`, e.g: foobar.node

Comment: THis is excellent.  I am using clang++, does anyone know the right flags for that (on Lion), and (on Mavericks) if possible?

Comment: clangs options are usually compatible with gccs.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried in Linux but at least in OSX I had to use `-undefined suppress` and `-flat_namespace` since node.js(v0.4.12) has it's own statically linked v8 library in the executable.

The following Makefile compiles mod.cpp into **mod.node** in MacOSX Lion:

```
all: mod.node
    node app.js

mod.o: mod.cpp
    g++ -g -fPIC -DPIC -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -m64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -I/usr/local/include/node mod.cpp -c -o mod.o

mod.node: mod.o
    g++ -flat_namespace mod.o -o mod.node -undefined suppress -bundle -L/usr/local/lib

clean:
    rm mod.o
    rm mod.node
```

$ file mod.o

```
mod.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

$ file mod.node

```
mod.node: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Running make:

```
node app.js
{ hello: 'World' }
```

**Note:** The source code of mod.cpp it's from the [Addons tutorial](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/addons.html)